# Finding the the number of Lattice paths with three steps.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

We define a nice path of length as a path on a lattice from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ such as every step in it is: $r=(0,1)$ , $u=(1,0)$ and $v=(1,2)$, and it does not go under the line $y=x$.

A. Write a formula for the generating function that counts the number of the nice paths.

B.Solve the above formula and find an expression for the number of these paths of length n.

C.Find the number of $(1,2)$ steps in all paths of length n.

I started with drawing the possible paths for $n=1,2,3,4$, getting that we have $1,3,9,27$ paths (respectively) if I did really succeed to count all the possible paths for each $n$.

So, then I concluded that each legal path (which is mentioned above) is:

Every path = $\epsilon$ or v(every path) u (every path) or r(every path) u (every path).

Whhere $\epsilon$ denote the empty path.

If $A(x)$ the generating function and x denote the number of steps then I get:

$A(x)=1+(xA(x))(xA(x))+(xA(x))(xA(x))$.
$A(x)=1+x^2A(x)^2+x^2A(x)^2$

In B. I can do this after extracting $A(x)$
With finding the coefficient of $x^n$ in $A(x)$.

C. I don't understand if this is related to statistics on the number of (1,2) steps..

I'm not sure if my way of thinking is correct or not, I discovered that my way is not accurate. I'll be glad if you can correct me, and explain it.

Comment: Your arithmetic is wrong in going from $xA(x)xA(x)$ to $x^2A(x)$; you want $x^2A^2(x)$ there. Elsewise that looks mostly correct, though I haven't checked closely. One way to do (c) is to consider a more specialized generating function that counts the number of paths $A_{n,k}$ from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ with $k$ (1,2) steps; then $A_n=\sum_k A_{n,k}$ is the answer to (b), and $\sum_k kA_{n,k}$ will give you the quantity you're looking for in (c).

Comment: I'm missing something, I calculated the g.f many times where x counts different steps, but it was wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We derive a generating function $A(t)$ where $[t^n]A(t)$, the coefficient of $t^n$ in $A(t)$ gives the number of nice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$. We conveniently  encode a step in $x$-direction as $x$ corresponding to $u=(1,0)$, a step in $y$-direction as $y$ corresponding to $r=(0,1)$ and encode written in parenthesis $(xy^2)$ a step corresponding to $v=(1,2)$.

> We consider the following symbolic equation
> \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{A}=\varepsilon + t\times\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{A}+t^2\times\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{A}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

and interpret (1) as the set $\mathcal{A}$ of nice paths which is built from

- the empty path or
- a diagonal step of length $1$,  which is realised as $yAxA$ where $A$ represents a nice path or
- a diagonal step of length $2$, which is realised as $(xy^2)AxA$ where $A$ represents a nice path.

The idea here is to consider the *diagonal* step $yx$ with length $1$ and the *diagonal* step $(xy^2)x$ with length $2$ as basic building blocks.

> From (1) we derive the functional equation
> \begin{align*}
> A(t)&=1+tA(t)^2+t^2A(t)^2\\
> \end{align*}
> and obtain the generating function
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A(t)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4t-4t^2}}{2t(1+t)}}\\
> &=1+t+3t^2+9t^3+\color{blue}{31}t^4+113t^5+431t^6+\cdots
> \end{align*}
> where the last line was calculated with some help of Wolfram Alpha.

The blue marked $31$ nice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(4,4)$ are
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{llll}
yyyyxxxx&yyxxyxyx&(xy^2)yxxyx&yx(xy^2)xyx\\
yyyxyxxx&yxyyyxxx&(xy^2)xyyxx&yyx(xy^2)xx\\
yyyxxyxx&yxyyxyxx&(xy^2)xyxyx&yxy(xy^2)xx\\
yyyxxxyx&yxyyxxyx&y(xy^2)yxxx&yyxx(xy^2)x\\
yyxyyxxx&yxyxyyxx&y(xy^2)xyxx&yxyx(xy^2)x\\
yyxyxyxx&yxyxyxyx&y(xy^2)xxyx&(xy^2)(xy^2)xx\\
yyxyxxyx&(xy^2)yyxxx&yy(xy^2)xxx&(xy^2)x(xy^2)x\\
yyxxyyxx&(xy^2)yxyxx&yx(xy^2)yxx\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}

**Note:** The sequence $1,1,3,9,31,113,431,\dots$ is archived in OEIS as *[A052709](https://oeis.org/A052709)*.

> We can also conveniently use the generating function $A(t)$ to obtain the number of $(1,2)$-steps which occur in the nice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$. We mark the occurrence of an $(1,2)$-step, i.e. $(xy^2)$ in the symbolic equation (1) with $q$ and consider
> \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{A}_q=\varepsilon + t\times\mathcal{A}_q\times\mathcal{A}_q+q\cdot t^2\times\mathcal{A}_q\times\mathcal{A}_q\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> We obtain from (2) the generating function
> \begin{align*}
> A(t;q)&=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4t-4qt^2}}{2t(1+qt)}\\
> &=1+t+(q+2)t^2+(4q+5)t^3+(\color{blue}{2q^2+15q+14})t^4\tag{3}\\
> &\qquad+(15q^2+56q+42)t^5+\cdots
> \end{align*}
> and look at the polynomial $[t^4]A(t;q)=2q^2+15q+14$ which provides a refinement of the $31$ nice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(4,4)$. We have in accordance with the listed paths above:
>
> - $14$ paths which have no occurrence of $(xy^2)$,
> - $15$ paths which contain $(xy^2)$ precisely once and
> - $2$ paths which contain $(xy^2)$ precisely twice.

**Number $P_n$ of nice paths with $(1,2)$-steps:**

We derive the number $P_n$ of nice paths which contain $(1,2)$-steps from the generating function $A(t;q)$. Looking again at $[t^4]A(t;q)=2q^2+15q+14$ we see we have to sum up the terms with a factor $q$ evaluated at $q=1$. We can isolate the constant term by evaluating $[t^4]A(t;q)$ at $q=0$.
In order to derive the terms with factor $q$ we calculate the number of nice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ which contain $(1,2)$-steps as
\begin{align*}
P_n=[t^n]\left(A(t;1)-A(t;0)\right)\qquad\qquad n\geq 0\tag{4}
\end{align*}

**Number $V_n$ of $(1,2)$-steps in nice paths:**

We can also count the number $V_n$ of $(1,2)$-steps in nice paths. In order to get e.g. the $\color{blue}{19}$ $(1,2)$-steps in the paths from $(0,0)$ to $(4,4)$ we differentiate $[t^4]A(t;q)$ w.r.t. $q$ and evaluate at $q=1$:
\begin{align*}
V_4=[t^4]\left(\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial q}A(t;q)\right|_{q=1}\right)=(4q+15)|_{q=1}\color{blue}{=19}
\end{align*}

In general we have
\begin{align*}
V_n&=[t^n]\left(\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial q}A(t;q)\right|_{q=1}\right)\\
&=[t^n]\left.\left(\frac{t}{(1+qt)\sqrt{1-4t(1+qt))}}-\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4t(1+qt)}}{2(1+qt)^2}\right)\right|_{q=1}\tag{5}\\
&=[t^n]\left(t^2+4t^3+(\color {blue}{(4q+15)}t^4+(30q+56)t^5\right.\\
&\qquad\left.\big.+(15q^2+168q+70)t^6+\cdots\big)\right|_{q=1}
\end{align*}

**Calculation of $P_n$ and $V_n$:**

We manually calculate the polynomial $p_n(q)=[t^n]A(t;q)$ from which we can easily deduce $P_n$ and $V_n$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{p_n(q)}&=\color{blue}{[t^n]}\color{blue}{A(t;q)}\\
> &=[t^n]\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4t(1+qt)}}{2t(1+qt)}\\
> &=[t^n]\left(1-\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{j}\left(-4t\right)^j\left(1+qt\right)^j\right)\frac{1}{2t(1+qt)}\tag{6}\\
> &=2[t^n]\sum_{j=1}^\infty\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{j}\left(-4t\right)^{j-1}\left(1+qt\right)^{j-1}\\
> &=2[t^n]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{j+1}\left(-4t\right)^{j}\left(1+qt\right)^{j}\\
> &=[t^n]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{2j}{j}\frac{1}{j+1}t^j(1+qt)^j\tag{7}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{2j}{j}\frac{1}{j+1}[t^{n-j}](1+qt)^j\tag{8}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{2j}{j}\frac{1}{j+1}\binom{j}{n-j}q^{n-j}}\tag{9}
> \end{align*}

**Comment:**

- In (6) we use the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* expansion.
- In (7) we use the binomial identity $\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{j}=\frac{1}{2^{2j-1}}\binom{2j-2}{j-1}\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j}$.
- In (8) we apply the rule $[t^{p-q}]A(t)=[t^p]t^qA(t)$.
- In (9) we select the coefficient of $t^{n-j}$.

> We finally conclude from (4), (5) and (9)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{P_n}&=p_n(1)-p_n(0)
> \color{blue}{=\sum_{j=\left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil}^{n-1}\binom{2j}{j}\binom{j}{n-j}\frac{1}{j+1}}\\
> \color{blue}{V_n}&=\left.\left(\frac{d}{dq}p_n(q)\right)\right|_{q=1}
> \color{blue}{=\sum_{j=\left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil}^{n-1}\binom{2j}{j}\binom{j}{n-j}\frac{n-j}{j+1}}
> \end{align*}
> and get as plausibility check
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{P_4}&=\sum_{j=2}^3\binom{2j}{j}\binom{j}{4-j}\frac{1}{j+1}=\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}\frac{1}{3}+\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{1}\frac{1}{4}\\
> &=2+15\color{blue}{=17}\\
> \color{blue}{V_4}&=\sum_{j=2}^3\binom{2j}{j}\binom{j}{4-j}\frac{4-j}{j+1}=\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}\frac{2}{3}+\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{1}\frac{1}{4}\\
> &=4+15\color{blue}{=19}\\
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with the calculations above.

Comment: @user726608: You're welcome. Take a look e.g. at $[t^4]A(t;q)$. In order to find the $17$ occurrences of $(1,2)$-steps in the nice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(4,4)$ we have to evaluate the polynomial $2q^2+15q+14$ at $q=1$ and subtract the constant part $14$. So, we have to calculate $[t^4]\left(A(t;1)-A(t;0)\right)$. If you need some support I can add some information after work. Regards,

Comment: Yes, thanks, they ask for all the (1,2) steps in all the paths, we shouldn't consider paths which have more that one (1,2) appearances as they give us 2 (or more) (1,2) steps? @Markus Scheuer

Comment: You mean that the method we did in c is wrong? (Then I don't see a way to overcome it)

Comment: I meant that, what we've calculated in part c is what we've supposed to compute? (I may be missed with  the meaning of "number of all (1,2) steps in all the paths of length n")

Comment: It means that we must count "all" the (1,2) steps (in all the mentioned 
 paths) (for example if there are two occurrence of (1,2) steps in a certain path then we take q^2) how can we take the sketch now? @Markus Scheuer

Comment: @user726608: I've updated my answer accordingly. Btw. generating functions are cool, aren't they? :-)

Comment: @user726608: FInal update to also manually derive the wanted number. Nice problem. Regards,

Comment: Yeah, you're perfect!

Comment: @user726608: Many thanks for your nice comment. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there are complications that make it not quite so straightforward as you've written. Most notably, what you have is the generating function for the number of paths with $n$ *steps* — but since you have one step that's longer than the others, that won't get you the number of paths **to** $(n,n)$. Instead, try writing a recurrence relation for $A_n$ in terms of smaller $A_i$ using the same approach that you sketched out loosely; you should find a very similar answer. (I suspect you're missing a factor of $x$ one way or the other in one of your terms, but writing the relation explicitly should make it clear.)

For (c), you'll need to expand your generating-function approach a bit. Let $A_{n,k}$ be the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ that contain $k$ (1,2)-steps. Then with a similar approach to what you've done for determining the number of steps you should be able to generate a recurrence relation for $A_{n,k}$, or equivalently an equation for the generating function $A(x,y)=\sum_n\sum_kA_{n,k}x^ny^k$. Once you've got this, the quantity that (c) asks for is $B_n=\sum_kkA_{n,k}$ (note that $A_n$ is just $\sum_kA_{n,k}$ without the multiplying factor). As a further hint if you aren't familiar with the particular manipulation that's relevant here, consider the effect of the $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ operator on $A(x,y)$.

Comment: It was a typo.I tried to find the generating function, however I'm getting that the coifficient of x^n is inappropriate to what I've seen in my checking..is the way I counted the paths wrong?

Comment: Oh! I know what's wrong. I will amend this answer a bit.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what is the mistake..I took same sketch i mentioned but tried to choose another approach for x...